# Force evaluation of a counter in endnote

Tags: counters, endnotes

I have exercises in a handout and I would like to get the solutions of these exercises at the end of the handout.

For this purpose, I'am using `endnotes` package in the following way:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{endnotes}

\newcounter{cptdef}[section]
\renewcommand{\thecptdef}{\thesection.\arabic{cptdef}}

\newenvironment{theorem}{\textbf{Theorem \thecptdef}.}{\par\medskip}

\newenvironment{exo}{\refstepcounter{cptdef}\noindent\textbf{Exercise \thecptdef. }}{\par\medskip}


\def\enotesize{\normalsize}
\def\makeenmark{\relax}
\def\notesname{Solutions}
\def\thesoluces{\theendnotes}



\begin{document}

\section{Pyth agore}
\begin{theorem}$A^2+B^2 = C^2$\end{theorem}

\begin{exo} 
    Prove this theorem
    \soluce{Use Pytha!}
\end{exo}

\begin{exo}
    Prove Al-Kashi's theorem.
    \soluce{Blabla}
\end{exo}

\section{Arithmetic}
\begin{exo}1+1 = ? \soluce{2} \end{exo}

\thesoluces
\end{document}
```

It works pretty good, except the numbering of the answers. Here is the rendering:

```
1. Pythagore
Theorem 1.1: A²+B²=C²

Exercise 1.2: Prove it
Exercise 1.3: Prove Al-Kashi

2. Arithmetic
Exercise 2.1: 1+1 = ?

Solutions
Exercise 2.1: Use Pytha
Exercise 2.1: Blabla
Exercise 2.1: 2
```

The fact is `endnotes` write `Exercise \thecptdef.` in the `handout.ent` and this file is parsed when I call `\thesoluces`, thus the counter is not "evaluated" at the right time.

Is it possible to "force" the `\thecptdef` to be evaluated in the following:

```
\def\soluce#1{%
      \endnotetext{\small\textbf{Exercice \thecptdef. } #1 \medskip}
}
```

In this way, the `handout.ent` will contain "Exercise 1.2", "Exercise 1.3", ...

Comment: Please provide a document that is compilable, not just fragments. I suspect some `\expandafter` or `\edef` sorcery ;-) And isn't the package called `endnotes`?

Answer (score 3):

```
\def\soluce#1{%
      \edef\tmp{%
      \noexpand\endnotetext{\noexpand\small\noexpand\textbf
        {Exercise \thecptdef. } #1\noexpand\par\noexpand\medskip}}\tmp
}
```

forces the expansion of `\thecptdef.` before `\endnotetext` is called. I also added a `\par` to ensure the correct linespacing for the `\small` text, and to ensure the final `\vspace` is executed in vertical mode.

---

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{endnotes}

\newcounter{cptdef}[section]
\renewcommand{\thecptdef}{\thesection.\arabic{cptdef}}

\newenvironment{theorem}{\textbf{Theorem \thecptdef}.}{\par\medskip}

\newenvironment{exo}{\refstepcounter{cptdef}\noindent\textbf
      {Exercise \thecptdef. }}{\par\medskip}


\def\enotesize{\normalsize}
\def\makeenmark{\relax}
\def\notesname{Solutions}
\def\thesoluces{\theendnotes}

\def\soluce#1{%
      \edef\tmp{%
      \noexpand\endnotetext{\noexpand\small\noexpand\textbf
       {Exercise \thecptdef. } #1\noexpand\par\noexpand\medskip}}\tmp
}

\begin{document}

\section{Pyth agore}
\begin{theorem}$A^2+B^2 = C^2$\end{theorem}

\begin{exo} 
    Prove this theorem
    \soluce{Use Pytha!}
\end{exo}

\begin{exo}
    Prove Al-Kashi's theorem.
    \soluce{Blabla}
\end{exo}

\section{Arithmetic}
\begin{exo}1+1 = ? \soluce{2} \end{exo}

\thesoluces
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, it seems that a } is missing after `\noexpand\medskip}` isn't it? Moreover, when I compile I have the following error: ! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [parameter stack size=10000].
\csuse #1->
           \ifcsname #1\endcsname \csname #1\expandafter \endcsname \fi

Comment: @Sebastien I added the missing `}` the answer was not tested as you did not provide any usable test file, the code in your question just makes `! Undefined control sequence.
l.26     \soluce`

Comment: @Sebastien but I just tried it, it works for me, I'll add document to answer